# Stop redirect on clicking a link

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to stop the page from redirecting on clicking a link? I'm searching for a function like preventDefault().

Comment: Uhm, `preventDefault` **is** plain JavaScript > https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()` actually is vanilla JavaScript and can achieve what you're looking for.

For example, with the following markup:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" id="preventme">Google</a>
```

We can attach the following JavaScript to prevent the browser from heading to `http://www.google.com/` when the `<a>` element is clicked:

```
document.getElementById('preventme').addEventListener(
    'click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false
);
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s2mpmom8/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this little function in your click handler:

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

Comment: also, as said in earlier comment, preventDefault is plain JavaScript.

Comment: @BenM. Totally true. It could help tho if preventDefault() not doing it.

Comment: How, in the case of clicking an `<a>` element?

Comment: Depends on the full code/functionallity, which is not provided here.

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler function that will "return false"

Comment: Returning `false` from an event does more than preventing its default behaviour.

Comment: @SergeyBob What if the event still needs propagating up the DOM tree?

Comment: Mmmm, i dont know, did the guy ask? What if the guy needs an extra kidney? Should my answer include it? :)

Comment: Haha, my point is that `return false` is not a good solution for extensibility when it comes to handling events. There's no need to `return false`, you can simply use `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Well, its simple and easy solution that is widely used, and is better supported. Anyway, that does answer the question, your opinion is interesting and valuable, of course, but doesnt mean my answer is wrong

Comment: Indeed. I didn't say your answer was wrong (hence why I didn't downvote) :)